# Openerp related fields in HR module hr_employee with Department, Division...etc and Location

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I have these four classes in my OpenERP hr module as below

**res_company --->hr_department-->hr_division-->hr_section**

```
    class company_new_registration(osv.osv):
        _name = "hr.company.n.registration"
        _description = "Company"
        _columns = {
            'name': fields.char('Company Name', size=128, required=True),
            'depts': fields.one2many('hr.dept.n.registration', 'company_id', 'Dept'),

        }
    company_new_registration()

    class dept_new_registration(osv.osv):
        _name = "hr.dept.n.registration"
        _description = "depts"
        _columns = {
            'name': fields.char('Dept Name', size=128, required=True),
            'company_id': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Company Name', required=True),
            'divisions': fields.one2many('hr.division.n.registration', 'dept_id', 'Division'),
            'resres':fields.one2many('res.users','alias_id')

        }

    dept_new_registration()

    class division_new_registration(osv.osv):
        _name = "hr.division.n.registration"
        _description = "Divisions"
        _columns = {
            'name': fields.char('Division Name', size=128, ),
            'dept_id': fields.many2one('hr.dept.n.registration', 'Dept. Name', select=True, required=True),
            'sections': fields.one2many('hr.section.n.registration', 'division_id', 'Section'),

        }

    division_new_registration()

    class section_new_registration(osv.osv):
        _name = "hr.section.n.registration"
        _description = "sections"
        _columns = {
            'name': fields.char('Name', size=128), 
            'section_name': fields.char('Section Name', size=128, required=True),
            'division_id': fields.many2one('hr.division.n.registration', 'Division Name', select=True, required=True),
        }

    section_new_registration()
```

all four classes in **one2many** relationship and all the above classes are have name field and one another field to have relationship respectively.

Also there is another class in my module which named **hr_location** which need to keep all above four classes references in order to create Organization structure.

my questions are:

1. I need to create a field which displays **"Company name/ Department name/Division name/ Section name"** in **hr_location** table when ever I create a new Section or Division or etc
2. I need to create four related field which stored **company_id, department_id, division_id and section_id** in **hr_employee** table when ever I select the location from above (in previous question) field.

Comment: could you please post part of the source code of the four models?

Comment: yep sure I will post

Comment: i improved your formatting. Forvige me but i also changed the name of the field from *section_id* to *division_id* for consistence.

Comment: Thank you so much, I also forgot to change it... thanks again

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create into section_new_registration a computed field which concatenate the names of the whole hierarchy in the **"Company name/ Department name/Division name/ Section name"** you need.

Or you can override the create instead of an computed field:

```
def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
     company = self.pool.get('res.company').browse(cr, uid, values['company_id'], context=context)
     dept = self.pool.get('hr.dept.n.registration').browse(cr, uid, values['department_id'], context=context)
     division = self.pool.get('hr.division.n.registration').browse(cr, uid, values['division_id'], context=context)

     values['name'] = company.name + '/' + dept.name + '/' + division.name + '/'+ values['section_name']
     return super(hr_location, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
```

Second, you need to create into **hr_location** a field such

```
'section_id': fields.many2one('hr.section.n.registration')
```

to accomplish your point (1)

Third, for your point (2) you need to create five fields as follows:

```
'location_id': fields.many2one('hr.location')
'section_id': fields.related('location_id', 'section_id', type='many2one', relation='hr.section.n.registration', store=True)
'division_id': fields.related('location_id', 'section_id', 'division_id', type='many2one', relation='hr.division.n.registration', store=True)
'department_id': fields.related('location_id', 'section_id', 'division_id', 'dept_id', type='many2one', relation='hr.dept.n.registration', store=True)
'company_id': fields.related('location_id', 'section_id', 'division_id', 'dept_id', 'company_id', type='many2one', relation='res.company', store=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer Ruffolo, could you help me with creating the function for updating the hr_location table's name as well. so far I have wrote this....